# how to ignore _id and _class when write mongodb document?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate

I have one collection which stores time-series data, only insert and query, no update and delete, as `MongoTemplate` genenrates `_id` and `_class` fields automatically, these two fields consume disk space and I don't need them, how can I ignore them when writing?

PS: I know how to ignore _class globally, how to ignore _class only for one specific collection?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to enable the global _class & _id and disable it only certain conditions.

Anyway for the problem, if you want to discard those fields, you can just convert your POJO to a raw json and directly save it in Mongo.

```java
Document document = Document.parse(jsonString)
mongoTemplate.getCollection("collection").insertOne(document);
```

You can create a wrapper **write method** to incorporate these changes.

Comment: thanks, it ignored _class field, _id still exists. I am developping a IoT system, I store device log into a collection, this collection only need `mac`, `time`, `content`  fields. as collection will grow bigger and bigger, _class & _id fields will consume too much space, this is reason I want to disable _class & _id on this collection.

Comment: An overkill would be define a new MongoTemplate bean just for this collection which ignore _class & _id field.  But would solve your purpose.